# How to perform insert operation on easy table using Table.js on Azure

Tags: azure

I am trying to insert data in azure easy table.
But in New Azure portal, I don't know where to write my insert script.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: hi @manetsus i m using azure new portal ..i have easy table and i want to insert data in that table by using insert script ..i didn't get any  azure documentation of how to write insert delete and update script .

Comment: In Azure classic portal with respect to table i have separate insert ,delete and update script but in new portal nothing like that, please help i got stuck on that issue from last week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy ..check below sample code

```
table.insert(function insertData(item) {
console.log("item............."+item);
var tempvari = item.execute();
console.log("tempvari......................." + tempvari);
return tempvari;
});
```